# Getting error when using mp.stop() in android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, message

I am encountering this error whenever i do a mp.stop in android, basically an sms with body RING:(password) to play the audio and STOP:(password) to stop the audio. The play is working fine but not the stop.

```
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.braincandy);

    if (correctSHA1 != null) {    


        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {

          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();   
          if (bundle != null) {

          Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
          SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];   

          for(int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {   
              smsMessage[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            if (smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().contains("RING:")) {    
                String[] tokens = smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().split(":"); 
                Log.v(TAG, "RING SMS Message keyword detected");

                if (tokens.length >= 2) {    

                    Log.v(TAG, "Token 1: " + tokens[0]);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Token 2: " + tokens[1]);

                    String SHA1hash = PhoneFinder.getSHA1(tokens[1]);   

                    Log.v(TAG, "SHA1 Hash:" + SHA1hash);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Correct SHA1:" + correctSHA1);

                    if (SHA1hash.equals(correctSHA1)) {    
                        Log.v(TAG, "SHA1 hash matched!");
                        this.abortBroadcast(); //Abort Broadcast for SMS Message

                        String to = smsMessage[i].getOriginatingAddress (); 
                        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault(); 

                        sm.sendTextMessage (to, null, "success!", null, null);
                        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
                        Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, "Alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (context, 0, new Intent (context, PhoneFinder.class), 0);
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo (context, "GPS address", "You have been detected", contentIntent);
                        nm.notify (R.string.service_start, notification);

                        //context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
                        mp.start();

                        }    

                    }    
                } 
                else if (smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().contains("STOP:")) {
                    String[] tokens = smsMessage[i].getMessageBody().split(":"); 
                    Log.v(TAG, "STOP SMS Message keyword detected");

                    if (tokens.length >= 2) {    

                        Log.v(TAG, "STOP Token 1: " + tokens[0]);
                        Log.v(TAG, "STOP Token 2: " + tokens[1]);

                        String SHA1hash = PhoneFinder.getSHA1(tokens[1]);   

                        Log.v(TAG, "STOP SHA1 Hash:" + SHA1hash);
                        Log.v(TAG, "STOP Correct SHA1:" + correctSHA1);

                        if (SHA1hash.equals(correctSHA1)) {    
                            Log.v(TAG, "STOP SHA1 hash matched!");
                            this.abortBroadcast(); //Abort Broadcast for SMS Message


                        //  context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
                            if (mp.isPlaying())
                                mp.pause();
                            }    
                }
```

Logcat error:

```
07-22 10:11:30.082: V/Logging Activity(7207): New Broadcast Receiver
07-22 10:11:30.082: V/Logging Activity(7207): Password: passwd
07-22 10:11:30.087: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): native_setup
07-22 10:11:30.087: V/MediaPlayer(7207): constructor
07-22 10:11:30.092: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setListener
07-22 10:11:30.092: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): setDataSourceFD: fd 57
07-22 10:11:30.092: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setDataSource(57, 652, 2625504)
07-22 10:11:30.107: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setVideoSurfaceTexture
07-22 10:11:30.107: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepare
07-22 10:11:30.112: V/MediaPlayer(7207): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
07-22 10:11:30.112: V/MediaPlayer(7207): New video size 0 x 0
07-22 10:11:30.112: V/MediaPlayer(7207): callback application
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): back from callback
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepared
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): signal application thread
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): callback application
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): back from callback
07-22 10:11:30.117: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepare complete - status=0
07-22 10:11:30.122: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(7207): SMS SC timestamp: 1342923088000
07-22 10:11:30.132: V/Logging Activity(7207): RING SMS Message keyword detected
07-22 10:11:30.132: V/Logging Activity(7207): Token 1: RING
07-22 10:11:30.132: V/Logging Activity(7207): Token 2: abc123
07-22 10:11:30.137: V/Logging Activity(7207): SHA1 Hash:6367c48dd193d56ea7b0baad25b19455e529f5ee
07-22 10:11:30.137: V/Logging Activity(7207): Correct SHA1:6367c48dd193d56ea7b0baad25b19455e529f5ee
07-22 10:11:30.137: V/Logging Activity(7207): SHA1 hash matched!
07-22 10:11:30.167: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): start
07-22 10:11:30.167: V/MediaPlayer(7207): start
07-22 10:11:30.202: E/MediaPlayer(7207): mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.
07-22 10:11:30.202: I/MediaPlayer(7207): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
07-22 10:11:30.202: E/MediaPlayer(7207): mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/Logging Activity(7207): New Broadcast Receiver
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/Logging Activity(7207): Password: passwd
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): native_setup
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/MediaPlayer(7207): constructor
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setListener
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): setDataSourceFD: fd 57
07-22 10:11:37.592: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setDataSource(57, 652, 2625504)
07-22 10:11:37.612: V/MediaPlayer(7207): setVideoSurfaceTexture
07-22 10:11:37.612: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepare
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): New video size 0 x 0
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): callback application
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): back from callback
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepared
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): signal application thread
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): callback application
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): back from callback
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): prepare complete - status=0
07-22 10:11:37.617: D/Gsm/SmsMessage(7207): SMS SC timestamp: 1342923096000
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP SMS Message keyword detected
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP Token 1: STOP
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP Token 2: abc123
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP SHA1 Hash:6367c48dd193d56ea7b0baad25b19455e529f5ee
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP Correct SHA1:6367c48dd193d56ea7b0baad25b19455e529f5ee
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/Logging Activity(7207): STOP SHA1 hash matched!
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer(7207): isPlaying: 0
07-22 10:11:37.617: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(7207): isPlaying: 0
07-22 10:11:37.617: E/MediaPlayer(7207): mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.
07-22 10:11:37.617: I/MediaPlayer(7207): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
07-22 10:11:37.617: E/MediaPlayer(7207): mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.
```

Comment: We can't help you with out your part of codes. It seems to lack of listeners!

Comment: @dythe If my answer helps you than don't forgot to accept it and up vote me . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.braincandy);
mp.pause();
```

You are not allowed to call pause() right after initializing a media player. You can call it only at certain states. These states are defined by a state diagram illustrated in below figure.

**EDIT:** You said you want it to stop, so things have changed.

- Move the initialization inside the RING clause and call start().
- Call stop() directly inside STOP clause and call reset() right after.
- Ensure that a RING is always followed by a STOP and a STOP is followed by a RING message. Otherwise, you will call the MediaPlayer functions in wrong states and get the same errors.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work still require on prepared listener, i don't really understand how the on prepared listener works.

Comment: You should do initialization only once, outside the if clause. You don't need onprepared listener.

Comment: Yeah, i changed it. Updated the code and Logcat in the post, no idea why it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to pause the music or stop the music? Or asked the other way around, do you want to resume the music when you receive RING or do you want to start it from the beginning?

Comment: Ok probably i wanted to stop it, but mp.stop() doesn't work, and when i receive RING i want it to start from the beginning

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It doesn't stop or gives an error?

Comment: Wouldn't placing the Initialization inside RING clause cause the STOP clause not to have mediaplayer declared?

Comment: No, declare it as a class variable and do the create part in RING and ensure that the code in RING is always executed before STOP. In other words, ignore STOP message if RING hasn't been called before and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You cant start media player until it get prepared and you cant pause media player if it isnt playing :)

So you have to make amendments in your code or you might want to take a look at a very nice tutorial

[Dealing with the Android Media Player](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/dealing-with-the-android-media-player/)

This will surely help you.

Thanks :)